# ¿Por que no Cambia el layout(Portrait/Landscape) cuando se rota el dispositivio?

Tags: android, layout

Tengo implementados pestañas con el viewpager, dependiendo la orientacion de la pantalla(Portrait/Landscape) deben cambiarse respectivamente el layout asignado para cada vista, pero no cambia, permanece con el layout que inicio la actividad, alguna idea

probe con cambiarle en el manifiesto la siguiente propiedad a la actividad:

```
....
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
....
```

pero sin resultado alguno

Comment: elimina eso que agregas ya que lo que realizaría es que no cambie el layout porque no destruye el activity, podrías agregar tu AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: ok... se lo quito pero como tengo datos en los controles, lo unico que consigo que se me arroje error, que opciones tengo????

Answer (score 3):

Lo que comentas en tu pregunta que trataste:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

únicamente sirve para no destruir la `Activity` al rotar el dispositivo pero no sirve de ninguna manera para permitir el rotado.

---

Revisa dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` si no tienes definida una orientación, ya sea en la aplicación o en una Activity:

```
 android:screenOrientation="< orientación >".
```

Si definiste

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

únicamente permitiria orientación vertical.

Si definiste

```
 android:screenOrientation="lanscape"
```

únicamente permitiria orientación horizontal.

Programaticamente se puede realizar lo mismo, revisa si no esta bloqueada la orientación:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

   //Define únicamente orientación vertical. 
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}
```

---

La otra opción es que en los settings de tu dispositivo este bloqueada la rotación! =P

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias @Elenasys ya probe todas las opciones que me preporcionas, pero solo funciona cuando no tengo datos en los controles... estoy muy agradecido con el tiempo que te tomas al responder....

Answer (score 2):

Este declaración no significa nada más que avisar al sistema que planificas de gestionar estos cambios en la configuración con tu propio código.

Entonces tienes que implementar:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

y dentro de eso hacer los cambios a los *Views* que necesitas.